# How to make Android app running on 7.0 compatible with server containing ECC certificate secp384r1

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, sslhandshakeexception, seccomp

After updating our server with ECC certificate - **secp384r1**, our client app running on **Android 7.0** could not establish communication with server but getting **OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE** exception.

Doing some investigation it is found that, Android 7.0 supports only secp256r1 and accidentally dropped secp384r1 and secp512r1 which is a known bug and fixed in Android 7.1.1 . Without upgrading to 7.1.1 is there any workaround for our client app possible to avoid this exception?

I have found some probable solutions after googling like -

- From here - [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/k-9-mail/RqgHRs1Wh24](http://These%20are%20both%20specific%20to%20Google%20dropping%20ECC%20curves%20in%20the%20crypto%20library.%20%20This%20could%20be%20fixed%20in%20K-9%20by%20bringing%20along%20a%20crypto%20library%20rather%20than%20using%20the%20system%20library%20as%20Chrome%20and%20Firefox%20do.), "*These are both specific to Google dropping ECC curves in the crypto library.  This could be fixed in K-9 by bringing along a crypto library rather than using the system library as Chrome and Firefox do.*"

Is it feasible to use different(self-developed) crypto lib rather than Android system lib like chrome/Firefox ?

- Does it make any help adding cipher suites to our client app which are used by server ?